# QGIS 3.10 projection error using BNG27700

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, windows-10, qgis-3

When opening a workspace with CRS BNG 27700 I am now getting an error that the following transformation is missing - OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS

If I use the next transformation in the list it puts my WMS layers with CRS 3857 slightly off where it should be, up to a few metres but enough to know it is not correct.

I have tried adding the Suggested file OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS into the folder named 'proj' it suggests. Note this folder was missing and was created by myself at the suggested location.

When I do this I get the following error when loading in my WMS in CRS 3857 ie. Google roads for example
[image]

as you can see this is far from ideal as it only shows this single strip of the layer I am wanting to view. Has anyone else got this same issue when using BNG 27700 in QGIS 3.10, running on Windows 10?

Comment: Is this a stand alone install or through the OSGeo4W installer?

Comment: Also do you have a QGIS_PATH\share\proj folder?

Comment: OSGeo4W Installer and there wasnt that folder, i had to create it and add the file

Comment: I can confirm I have exactly the same issue - every time I load QGIS since the update in OSGeo4W last week it warns me of sub-optimal conversion for OSGB. When following the instructions and installing the recommended file, I see exactly the same issue with CRS 3857. I have deleted and reinstalled on two different Windows 10 machines with the same effect. For the time being I'm living with the 1 to 2m error which results and not installing the proj file

Comment: There is an open ticket with the QGIS development team - the latest update is that this is an accepted bug and will hopefully be fixed in the next release 3.10.2 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33154

Comment: I can confirm that version 3.10.2 seems to fix the problem and is available via OsGeo4W - just update QGIS and drop OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb into the ../share/proj folder

Comment: That ticket is for a similar bug. But 3.10.2 does not fix this issue. The issues is still there with reprojecting rasters on the fly with the more precise transformation grid file.

Answer (score 3):

With the OSGeo4W installer you need to put the OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb file into:

C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj

This folder should already exist. But QGIS should also have shown a path to where it was looking for the file.

You can get the grid files (for other users, as OP already has them) from:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers

Edit:

While this is the correct way to install the grid files. This does not fix the issues, which was a bug in QGIS 3.12+.

Comment: the suggest File i should use for my transformation is OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb according to the pop-up i am receiving from QGIS. Do you suggest to use the OSTN02_NTv2.gsb file instead? Or can i add both? Ive never had any issues like this before when using QGIS for transformations. TIA

Comment: Nope. I edited the answer already. The OSTN02 is the older version.

Comment: I have added the OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS to my C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj folder but the problem still persists as only that thin strip of my layer showing. If I remove the .gsb file it displays as normal again but doesnt have the 1m accuracy transformation anymore, and is stating my preferred transformation cant be used anymore. Also without OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb added  I cant display layers taken from the capernicus DEM of Europe in ETRS 89 in a BNG 27700 workspace. Is this normal behaviour for QGIS 3.10?

Comment: Nope. I can add EPSG:3857 WMS layers no problem with the OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS transformation files and it shows the whole of the UK.

Comment: thats grand, must be an issue on my end somewhere. Will keep tinkering til i get it working as should be. Cheers for the advice for the OSGeo4W folders location

Comment: It seems you have a few issues on top of each other. I would go through them step by step. See if reprojecting with the grid files works with non WMS data. Then see if the WMS works on its own without reprojection. Then reproject the WMS, try a different WMS to see if it is a tile issue.

Comment: After some digging I have got your suggestion to work on my laptop and I have noticed some structure differences between it and my work PC i am trying to fix. on laptop the directory for OSGeo4W is 'C:\OSGeo4W64' and I added the .gsb file there (WMS now working fine) On my work PC the 'C:\OSGeo4W64' folder only contains an 'etc' and 'var' folder with the directory folders being stored at 'C:\Program Files\OSGeo4W'. This is where i added the .gsb file and it caused the display issue. Is there a way to move my directory out to 'C:\OSGeo4W64' like on my laptop? or is a re-install required?

Comment: I would say a reinstall is the best option. It sounds like you have the 32 bit version on your work computer.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with newer versions of OSGeo4W. I just did a fresh install of 64bit version with latest QGIS installations and problem is persisting. No such issues on my older installed versions from my laptop. Also another person is encountering this problem. What is the correct way of reporting such issues to the QGIS team?

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: I have added this file to the folder mentioned above. Now there is no error, although my result comes completely blank. I use the 3.10 version so far.
My query is here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351288/qgis-3x-viewshed-plugin-no-result-after-re-projection