# QGIS 3x Viewshed plugin no result after re-projection

Tags: qgis, dem, viewshed

Continuing the query here:
[QGIS 3x viewshed plugin returns wrong results for visibility map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350477/qgis-3x-viewshed-plugin-returns-wrong-results-for-visibility-map)

I was trying to set proper CRS for my DEM on the area, where I am currently working on.

Unfortunately, the reprojection wasn't successful.

After changing from EPSG:4326 (WGS84) and EPSG:27700 (1936 British National Grid), the QGIS says:
**Cannot use preferred transform between EPSG:27700 and EPSG:4326**

In the details I can find, that this transform is not available.

Basically, the layer is created, although I am getting nothing.

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I found, that I am not only one with this problem, which shows the question below:

[QGIS 3.10 projection error using BNG27700](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342280/qgis-3-10-projection-error-using-bng27700)

Sticking to the edvices there I downloaded the relevant file from the OS website

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers

and next, I have done the following steps:

1. Reprojection of the layer
2. Saving the SHP points again under the British grid EPSG 27700, making them visible for the plugin (otherwise I was getting the error stating, that "there are no points here", whereas there were projected for EPSG:4376
3. Generated the view with changes in the data attribute table (image below).

[image]

Unfortunately, the result is not acceptable, since I get the blank black canvas with 2 white smallish rectangles showing the location of my points.

[image]

What can I do to get my result right?

Comment: Upgrade to 3.10.2, then remove the grid files you downloaded. It only improves the accuracy of the reprojection by about a meter on the ground. So for a large scale analysis like this there will be no difference.

Comment: How about the newest version 3.12?

Comment: Yeah sorry, meant 3.12.2.

Comment: It's, unfortunately, the same pal :( With no error I got nothing

Comment: The question is a bit unclear now with the edits. Does the reprojecting work now? Is the DEM in EPSG:27700? What are the view shed settings? Bearing in mind that it is EPSG:27700, so the unit is meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, first of all, you must edit your data attribute table and make sure, that your range (radius) is wider than 1km or other small valuables.

[image]

In another case, we will get the blank canvas as I used to get when my radius was set on 1000 only.
Taking the close-up view into the situation I would see the 1km rectangles from my points.

[image]

When I changed my radius up to 200000 (200km), then I get proper render. However, when we create the viewshed there is one very important thing to mark. It's the Earth curvature option, which doesn't come as a default. We must remember to thick it before running the algorithm

[image]

Finally, our result will look like this:

[image]

which is very similar to the Heywhatsthat visibility cloak from that place:

[image]

The small mismatch between the Viewshed result and Heywhatsthat arises out from the SRTM difference and the DEM level of details. I used the basic DEM only, hence the cloak comprises bigger rectangles unlike in Heywhatsthat.